# OpenCV: Why create multiple Mat objects to transform an image's format?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have not worked with OpenCV for a while, so please bear with my beginner questions. I curiously thought of something as I was looking through OpenCV tutorials and sample code.

Why do people create multiple Mat images when going through multiple transformations? Here is an example:

```
Mat mat, gray, thresh, equal;
mat = imread("E:/photo.jpg");
cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(gray, equal);
threshold(equal, thresh, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

Example of a code that uses only *two* Mat images:

```
Mat mat, process; 
mat = imread("E:/photo.jpg");
cvtColor(mat, process, CV_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(process, process);
threshold(process, process, 50, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
```

Is there anything different between the two examples? Also, another beginner question: will OpenCV run faster when it only creates two Mat images, or will it still be the same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: using more different mats might be better for testing new stuff and debugging and might give code that's easier to read. but second one might be a little bit more efficient.

Comment: but: be aware that for example methods like cvtColor(input, input, code) will be inefficient for multiple calls because they are no in-place operations and have to allocate temporary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question comes down to, do you still need the unequalized image later on in the code? If you want to further process the gray image then the first option is better. If not, then use the second option.

Some functions might not work in-place; specifically, ones that transform the matrix to a different format, either by changing its dimensions (such as `copyMakeBorder`) or number of channels (such as `cvtColor`).

For your use case, the two blocks of code perform the same number of calculations, so the speed wouldn't change at all. The second option is obviously more memory efficient.